How to point stopword language in the R code filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
I use very common R-code to create ngram. I have a multilingual text, but the published code deals only with English. I know that the tidytext enables using other languages for stopwords. Please, advise how to apply them in the code.
I need for German and French.
text_grahp <- text_df %>%
  unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>%
  separate(bigram, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ") %>%
  filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
  filter(!word2 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
  filter(!is.na(word1)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(word2)) %>%
  count(word1, word2, sort=TRUE) %>%
  filter(n >= 9) %>% #here is a variable to check before to do it put a line text_graph right below the previous line
  graph_from_data_frame()

I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to do it.

You might need to use your own list of stopwords for other languages. There are lots online - such as here... https://countwordsfree.com/stopwords/german

Thank you, Andrew! I know how to do it for R tm and I know that there is stopwords("fr") command for tidytext, but how to put it in the line with the filter - have no idea. It's my first time I use tidytext.

You can just save the stopwords as a vector, and then replace stop_words$word in your code with the name of the vector.  There is also a stopwords R package, which includes many languages, which might make it easier.

In tidytext you can also get french stopwords with fr_stop <- get_stopwords(language = "fr"), for example.  "de" for German. This uses the stopwords package, as mentioned above. Use it the same way as stop_words in your code.
